# Java, EJB, Lock - synchronization for private fields?

Tags: synchronization, locking, ejb-3.1

I've got a follow-up question to:
[EJB 3.1 container managed concurrency vs. synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178947/ejb-3-1-container-managed-concurrency-vs-synchronized)

Is a Lock only preventing concurrent access to data within the persistence context, etc. or is it also providing synchronization for private fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to imagine that there is a per-bean `java.util.concurrent.ReadWriteLock` on which the container is calling `lock()` and `unlock()` around the method call on either the `readLock()` or `writeLock()`, depending on the configured `@Lock` for the method.  So, instance variables are protected.

However, be aware that a container-managed `@PersistenceContext` field is not "shared" state because the container actually injects a proxy object.  Each method call on that proxy `EntityManager` will delegate to a per-transaction `EntityManager`.  Since transactions are not shared across threads, it is thread-safe even if the bean is using `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)` with no other synchronization.